# how to create a CStirng from ConstUnsafePointer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

i know CString can init with UnsafePointer ,but how to create it with ConstUnsafePointer

the error of the code: ConstUnsafePointer is not convertible to UnsafePointer

```
     var result:ConstUnsafePointer = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, num)
     let cstr:CString = CString(result)
```

or how to convert it to UnsafePointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to go through `UnsafePointer`:

```
var result: ConstUnsafePointer<UInt8> = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, num)
let cstr: CString = CString(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please replace LENGTH with your variable.

```
var result: ConstUnsafePointer = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, num)
var resultToString: NSString = NSString(bytes: result, length: LENGTH, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
var cstring: CString = resultToString.UTF8String
```

Comment: If thats common in your code. Make it an extension!